# Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus in an equation

Tags: calculus, integration

So as stated in the fundamental theorem of Calculus

$ ∫_b^x f(t) = F(x) $

How would the theorem apply to this question as when finding $ f(4) $ in this equation?

$ ∫_b^{x^2} f(t)dt = x\sin(π x) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_b^xf (t)dt=F (x)\implies $$

$$F (x^2)=x\sin (\pi x) \implies$$

$$ F (x)=\sqrt {x}\sin (\pi\sqrt {x}) $$

and

$$f (t)=F'(t)$$

$$=\frac {\sin (\pi\sqrt {t})}{2\sqrt {t}}+\frac {\pi}{2}\cos (\pi\sqrt {t})$$

thus $$f (4)=\frac {\pi}{2} $$

Comment: So by applying the Fundamental theorem to the integral, you wouldn't have do differentiate both sides in order for F(t) to be F(x^2) and applying the chain rule to F(x^2)?

Comment: @Killimanjaro if you differentiate, you will get $f (x^2)2x=\sin (\pi x )+\pi x\cos (\pi x) $.

Comment: Would that be incorrect to do in this situation?

Comment: Yes.take $x=2$ to have $f (4) $.